# cakephp find all join

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

```
$order = $this->Order->find('all', array(
        'recursive' => 2,
        'conditions' => array(
            'Order.date' => $datefrom,
        ),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'purchase',
                'alias' => 'Purchase',
                'conditions'=> array(
                    'Purchase.pid = Order.pid', 
                )
            ),
                array(
                'table' => 'sales',
                'alias' => 'Sales',
                'conditions'=> array(
                    'Purchase.pid = Sales.pid', 
                )
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

Why does the above code doesn't select fields from purchase and sales, but only fields from order are returned. What is the necessary things to be added to make all data is returned. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I'm not sure if the 'type' and 'foreignKey' keys are required, but I typically include them when using the 'joins' key. Also I'm assuming the 'pid' is the correct foreign key.

```
$order = $this->Order->find('all', array(
    'recursive' => -1,
    'conditions' => array(
        'Order.date' => $datefrom,
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'purchase',
            'alias' => 'Purchase',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'foreignKey' => 'pid',
            'conditions'=> array(
                'Order.pid = Purchase.pid', 
            )
        ),
            array(
            'table' => 'sales',
            'alias' => 'Sales',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'foreignKey' => 'pid',
            'conditions'=> array(
                'Sales.pid = Purchase.pid', 
            )
        ),
    ),
));
```

If you already have relationships set up in the model, change the 'recursive' key to -1.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea,

```
'table' => 'purchase',
'alias' => 'Purchase',
```

isn't a typo, is it? Because I think, the usual name for the table according to cake-conventions would be 'purchases'... But I don't know your tables of course... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Controller::loadModel('User');
    Controller::loadModel('Answer');
    Controller::loadModel('Influence');
    $users = $this->User->find('all', array('joins' => array(
        array(
            'table'      => 'answers',
            'alias'      => 'Answer',
            'type'       => 'inner',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Answer.user_id = User.id'),
        ),
        array(
            'table'      => 'influences',
            'alias'      => 'Influence',
            'type'       => 'inner',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Influence.user_id=Answer.user_id',
            )
        )
    ),'fields' => array(
            'Answer.is_correct',
            'Answer.answer', 
            'Answer.date as answered_date',
            'Influence.signups',
            'Influence.clicks',
            'User.first_name',
            'User.last_name', 
            'User.email', 
            'User.phone', 
            'User.flybuys' )
    ));
```

In order to get fields from other tables You should specify the fields you want.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an association in **Order Model file**

**Model:**

```
 public $hasMany = array(

    'purchase' => array(

        'className' => 'purchase',

        'foreignKey' => 'pid',

        'dependent' => true,

        'counterQuery' => 'true'

    ),

    'sales' => array(

        'className' => 'sales',

        'foreignKey' => 'pid',

        'dependent' => true,

        'counterQuery' => 'true'
    ),
```

);

**Controller:**

```
    $order = $this->Order->find('all', array(

        'recursive' => 2,

        'conditions' => array(

            'Order.date' => $datefrom,

        )

    );
```

Now you can get Order, Purchase and Sales related records.

Enjoy...